# Issues setting up PhpStorm Remote Debugging for PHPUnit tests

Tags: laravel, phpunit, phpstorm, xdebug, homestead

I'm trying to setup Xdebug for debugging my Laravel application, running on Homestead. I've got it working for http requests from the browsers. But I can't seem to get it working for PHPUnit tests.

Here's my configuration:

[image: Config]

[image: Interpreter]

[image: XDebug]

[image: Homestead xdebug config]

[image: All I get is this!]

**xdebug Log when running unit tests with the debugger**

```
[2215] Log opened at 2020-02-08 21:34:36
[2215] I: Checking remote connect back address.
[2215] I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
[2215] I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
[2215] W: Remote address not found, connecting to configured address/port: 10.0.2.2:9000. :-|
[2215] I: Connected to client. :-)
[2215] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///home/vagrant/code/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.4.1" protocol_version="1.0" appid="2215" idekey="19707"><engine version="2.9.1"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2020 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[2215] <- eval -i 1 -- KHN0cmluZykoaW5pX2dldCgneGRlYnVnLmNvdmVyYWdlX2VuYWJsZScpLic7Jy5pbmlfZ2V0KCd4ZGVidWcucHJvZmlsZXJfZW5hYmxlJykuJzsnLmluaV9nZXQoJ3hkZWJ1Zy5yZW1vdGVfYXV0b3N0YXJ0JykuJzsnLmluaV9nZXQoJ3hkZWJ1Zy5yZW1vdGVfY29ubmVjdF9iYWNrJykuJzsnLmluaV9nZXQoJ3hkZWJ1Zy5yZW1vdGVfbW9kZScpKQ==
[2215] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="1"><property type="string" size="11" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[MTswOzE7MTtyZXE=]]></property></response>

[2215] <- feature_set -i 2 -n show_hidden -v 1
[2215] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="show_hidden" success="1"></response>

[2215] <- feature_set -i 3 -n max_depth -v 1
[2215] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="max_depth" success="1"></response>

[2215] <- feature_set -i 4 -n max_children -v 100
[2215] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="4" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>

[2215] <- feature_set -i 5 -n extended_properties -v 1
[2215] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="5" feature="extended_properties" success="1"></response>

[2215] <- feature_set -i 6 -n resolved_breakpoints -v 1
[2215] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="6" feature="resolved_breakpoints" success="1"></response>

[2215] <- status -i 7
[2215] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="status" transaction_id="7" status="starting" reason="ok"></response>

[2215] <- step_into -i 8
[2215] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_into" transaction_id="8" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///home/vagrant/code/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit" lineno="12"></xdebug:message></response>

[2215] <- breakpoint_set -i 9 -t line -f file:///home/vagrant/code/app/app/Http/Controllers/Api/AuthController.php -n 19
[2215] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="9" id="22150001" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[2215] <- breakpoint_set -i 10 -t line -f file:///home/vagrant/code/app/app/Http/Controllers/Api/AuthController.php -n 22
[2215] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="10" id="22150002" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[2215] <- breakpoint_set -i 11 -t line -f file:///home/vagrant/code/app/app/Http/Controllers/Api/AuthController.php -n 14
[2215] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="11" id="22150003" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[2215] <- breakpoint_set -i 12 -t line -f file:///home/vagrant/code/app/tests/Unit/ApiAuthTest.php -n 17
[2215] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="12" id="22150004" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[2215] <- stack_get -i 13
[2215] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="13"><stack where="{main}" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///home/vagrant/code/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit" lineno="12"></stack></response>

[2215] <- run -i 14
[2215] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="14" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[2215] <- run -i 15
[2215] Log closed at 2020-02-08 21:34:41
```

Comment: 1) What did you enter in "Debugger extension" field on your 2nd screenshot? WHY did you provide a path to some php.ini there where it asks for ACTUAL Xdebug file (xdebug.so) ??? 2) Login to your Homestead via SSH and execute `php -i` -- confirm if Xdebug will be present there...

Comment: I didn't put the php.ini path, I put the path to xdebug. Yeah it is present when I run `php -i`

Comment: 1) *"I didn't put the php.ini path, I put the path to xdebug"* Well .. screenshot clearly shows path to `20-xdebug.ini` there ... 2) Check what command IDE uses when it tires to debug (since it's a CLI mode it should show full command) and try running it manually in remote terminal 3) Enable Xdebug log and see what it will say -- will it try to connect and where. Right now it sounds like somehow different PHP might be used to run PHPUnit tests... odd.

Comment: @LazyOne ah - I think I'm following you now. That's putting me on the right track... I've checked the logs and can see that all of my breakpoints are showing as unresolved... added it to the post

Comment: @LazyOne - now, if I run the command on CLI on vagrant, I hit the breakpoints. Still no luck via PhpStorm however

Comment: Got it working by setting an ide_key in the configuration and setting up the test configuration to use the default project interpreter Thanks for putting me on the right track.

Comment: If you have resolved your issue -- please post your solution as an answer (you can accept it few hours later) -- this will help others in similar situations (as they will clearly see the solution).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same issue:

Set the default project interpreter to be the same remote interpreter you setup in the phpunit setup

[image]